# Outlook 2016 Won't Display Email Bodies

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've had 3 Outlook 2016 users contact me today with the same problem.

When they click any email, in there inbox, the preview pane is blank (as shown below):
[image]

Also, if they double-click any email (to open it in a new window) that email body is also blank.

I've tried updating Microsoft Office 2016 and the problem persisted after being fully updated.

Additionally, I tried deleting a user's email profile, and then re-syncing their email using Google App Sync (because the server is not exchange; it is Gmail). Even after a fresh re-sync the problem persists. Of course, if these users check their Gmail, the email bodies show just fine.

Have any of you experienced this issue, and if so, how did you get past it?

Comment: This was just another case of Microsoft releasing an update that breaks software. 2 of my 3 users are automatically not having the issue today (due to an emergency patch auto-applied last night by Microsoft).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our workaround that has been working for us run as administrator in cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.13901.20462
```

Comment: Thanks. This did work for the remaining user who was still having this problem this morning.